# Django static files loading for front page of site only

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.3.1 and Python 2.7 on WinVista.  I am experiencing the same problem whether on the local dev serer or when deployed to my host.

On the main page of my site static media shows:

http://www.drugpolicyreformmovement.com

On secondary pages CSS, images, etc. do not display:

http://www.drugpolicyreformmovement.com/newsarchive2003

http://www.drugpolicyreformmovement.com/newsarchive2010

or

http://www.drugpolicyreformmovement.com/newsarchive2009

The output of 'manage runserver' shows a 404 error for static media on those secondary 'newsarchive' pages.  Somehow 'document_root' is different on a secondary page as opposed to the main page, such that it looks in '/newsclippings2003/static' on those secondary pages instead of just looking in '/static' for everything as it should and like it did for the front page.

I don't know what of my URLconf is relevant to you so I have included the whole file here:

```
import os
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import ListView, YearArchiveView
from newsclippings.models import Article
from drugpolicyreformmovement.views import ArticleYearArchiveView

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', ListView.as_view(
       queryset = Article.objects.order_by("-date", "publication", "author", "headline"),
       context_object_name='articles',
       template_name='index.html')),
    (r'^newsarchive(?P<year>\d+)/$', ArticleYearArchiveView.as_view()),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
       { 'document_root' : os.path.join( os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static') }),
    # url(r'^drugpolicyreformmovement/', include('drugpolicyreformmovement.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Again, I think this is the problematic line:

```
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    { 'document_root' : os.path.join( os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static') }),
```

It doesn't matter what order I put URLconf entries.  This line was designed so I wouldn't have to make changes when I deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url in first page is

```
http://www.drugpolicyreformmovement.com/static/css/blueprint/print.css
```

in inner page

```
http://www.drugpolicyreformmovement.com/newsarchive2003/static/css/blueprint/print.css
```

just add `/` in url or use `{{ STATIC_URL }}`

for example

- `/static/css/blueprint/print.css`

or

- `<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/blueprint/print.css" />`

just set STATIC_ROOT in settings

see here:

- Django | Managing static files | Django documentation ->
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 1):

When I view-source your html, I see *relative* paths for your static assets. You need to use *absolute* paths!

**This is wrong:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/blueprint/screen.css" media="screen, projection">
```

**Use this:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/blueprint/screen.css" media="screen, projection">
```

Most likely it's your template that is incorrect, but you didn't show your template file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get it to serve the url that way, you should use the {{ STATIC_URL }} template tag in your templates. You still won't have to make changes when you deploy, and this way you can move stuff around and not worry about having another context variable to deal with.